# Mongoose - Joining based on Object name

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Currently, I have 3 schemas that I want to join. The first schema is the user schema.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "6147f87ac51f060e8c1bc8c7"
},
"userID": "344431410360090625",
"currency": 72590,
"level": 10,
"exp": 78.5,
"sp": 338,
"location": {
    "area": 2,
    "floor": 3
},
"inv": {
    "Rag Hood#363": {
        "emote": "",
        "description": "",
        "rarity": "Common",
        "type": "equipment",
        "image": "",
        "equipmentType": "helmet",
        "level": 20,
        "ascension": 0,
        "exp": 0,
        "quantity": 0,
        "expToLevelUp": 0,
        "equipped": false
    },
    "Jericho Jehammad": {
        "emote": "<:Jericho:823551572029603840>",
        "description": "Enhance your weapons with this mysterious item",
        "rarity": "Common",
        "type": "special",
        "image": "",
        "quantity": 7147,
        "listed": 6964
    },
},
"__v": 0,}
```

I want to be able to use the Object names of "Rag Hood#363" and "Jericho Jehammad". Firstly the equipment schema is shown below.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "61474cb047a1b66f2cb1b6d8"
},
"itemName": "Rag Hood",
"stats": {
    "defense": {
        "flat": 2,
        "multi": 0
    }
},
"equipmentType": "helmet",
"ascensionRequirements": [],
"statsUpPerLvl": {
    "defense": 0.5
}}
```

Next, the items schema is used to join Jericho Jehammad. Equipment in our database is named with #, with the item number after. While other items are identified with just the itemName.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "60c5c5e6d2d78c794d33b7ae"
},
"itemName": "Jericho Jehammad",
"emote": "<:Jericho:823551572029603840>",
"description": "",
"rarity": "Common",
"type": "special",
"image": ""}
```

I want to return an object that overrides the value if the value is present in the equipment and items schemas. If the value is not present, I will use the value present in the user schema.

Comment: The way you have structured your data is not okay for querying it efficiently. You can try defining by defining an `equipment ` array field in the `users` schema: `"inv": { equipment: [  { itemName: "Rag Hood#363",   _id; "61474cb047a1b66f2cb1b6d8", .... },  { itemName: "Jericho Jehammad",   _id; "some other value", .... }  ] `. Further refer this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Comment: I thought as much, I designed this database when I was way less experienced and this project has progressed beyond just being able to redesign the schema. I believe currently the 2 options I have is to either redesign the database and think of a way to migrate the data to fit the new schema or find another workaround to work with the current schema structure. Thanks for answering!